# What is the specification for 3-byte ASCII Signature Format?

Tags: specifications

Assuming there is an official spec for 3-byte ASCII Signature Format, and that it is not vendor specific.

Spec required for converting between formats and rendering.

Comment: I've never even heard of a 3-byte ASCII Signature, much less seen an official spec for one. Where did you come across it?

Comment: I did a Google search on this and found an explanation for plotting on a 1024x1024 bitmap.  So after reading that, I STILL have no idea what the question is.

Comment: @MarkRansom Customer signature capture from payment devices (pin and signature pads).

Comment: Is this relevant at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425643/embedding-ascii-hex-string-sigstring-into-html-page-not-base64

Comment: @MarkRansom not for me.

Comment: I found the spec embedded in vendor documentation. I also saw someone post the spec in a c# forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/1dc7421a-56dc-4698-ac33-9c79e25fde36/saving-series-of-point-data-in-c . I know of a different vendor that renders signatures that are in this format, but I still don't know if this proprietary or an open standard perhaps with a different name?